# Canon PowerShot S95 vs. Nikon Coolpix s9100

Tags: canon, nikon, point-and-shoot, compact-cameras

Which one is better buy?

Canon:

```
pros: auto and manual settings, better picture quality
cons: high price (330€), low zoom
```

Nikon:

```
pros: much lower price (230€), huge zoom
cons: no manual settings, lower picture quality
```

Is the picture quality of Canon really worth 100 euros?

Comment: The S95 would be my choice but I have no idea what you would use it for, it is impossible to give a definite answer.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered here as it's largely a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it probably mostly depends on what you want to do with your camera. this page might help you decide :

http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon_PowerShot_S95-vs-nikon-s9100

now, I'd personally go for the s95 for its size, Lens and its noise management. Its f2 Lens will allow you to shoot in darker situations and will give you more 'arty' shots because of the shallow depth of field. What it WON'T give you is huge zoom which I can understand can be a deal breaker for some people.

I hope this helps.